# Login Page Validation - AMP Script

Tags: marketing-cloud, validation, login

I have a requirement to validate the credentials in the login page for the data in one the DE that I have for the client.

I have created a login page in cloud pages/ landing pages ( salesforce marketing cloud).

I have email IDs as username, and their respective passwords stored in a Data Extension.

when user tries to login from login page, the credentials needs to be validated and then allow the user to the home page if the credentials are correct.

Let me know how the above task could be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Of course possible.

- You could use [LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) to check the username entered by the
  user in the login page with the Data extension data.
- Then you can use [Redirect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirect.htm) to redirect the user to next screens.
- You can use [UpdateData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatedata.htm) to update the data extensions with the information the users enter in the pages.

Make sure the password is encrypted/encoded while storing in the data extension.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and prompt reply. I shall try it the way you explained and will get back to you.

Comment: You should also have validation on the pages beyond the login so a user can't just bookmark the page and skip the validation.  This can be accomplished by using conditionals and either cookies or a parameter that can expire.  I usually have a second DE that has a retention period on it that contains `user | key`.  The key is a random GUID() created after login that is then passed to the subsequent pages - but after X time, it expires, requiring the user to relog. I then have conditionals on the pages to lookup against this DE to verify the key.